# How to modify the Trigger variable without altering the complete trigger in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger in sql server that contains more then thousand lines of code like

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[xyz] ON [dbo].[abc]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Here more then 100 field is there.
DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(2000)
--
--



DECLARE @IsPublished    BIT
DECLARE @ParentVersionedTemplateID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
--
--
```

Now I need to change the datatype of one of the field of this trigger. One possible way is copy and paste the whole code and use **ALTER** command and change the existing datatype whatever I want.

But I want to ask is there any other way where without drop and recreate the trigger or alter the complete trigger code can I modify the parameters of that trigger?

Comment: I don't think so. Also, I would advise you to try and create some smaller stored procedures that will be called from this trigger, just for readability.

Comment: ok @ZoharPeled. So only one possible way to alter a trigger that I mention in my question ?

Comment: AFAIK. perhaps someone else knows better. you should give your question some time to be answered.

Comment: If you use Management studio, just right-click the trigger and select **Modify** The studio will copy everything and you can just change what you want.

Comment: 10,000 lines in a trigger??? I also see the telltale signs of a trigger that isn't designed correctly. When you start seeing scalar variables in a trigger it is a good indication that the trigger is unable to handle multiple row operations.

Comment: I want to use query only. We have a custom DB Migration tools for database migration for that i need to use that query.

Comment: @SeanLange not 10,000 but it contains around 700 to 800 lines of code. This trigger is only for example i use here.

Comment: Well your example demonstrates a lack of understanding how to write setbased triggers. You should NOT have variables inside them, especially if they are set from inserted or deleted. In order to make the type of change you are asking you will have to either drop and recreate the trigger or alter it. There is no way around that.

Comment: Sorry for this misleading question.  My simple question is without drop and recreate the trigger or alter the complete trigger code can i modify the parameters of that trigger.

Comment: Simply put NO. You MUST alter the trigger or drop and create. For the record, triggers do not have parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in SQL Server to alter part of a Trigger.  You need to  rewriting the whole trigger (via `ALTER TRIGGER`).  My best suggestion would to to use SSMS, right click on the Trigger in question and select `Script Trigger as Alter`.  This would be the least amount of effort.

Comment: I want to use query only. We have a custom DB Migration tools for database migration for that i need to use that query

Comment: You could run the following`SELECT  [text] 
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.syscomments c ON o.object_id = c.id
WHERE o.[type] = 'TR' and o.[name] = 'triggerName'`  It will give you the `CREATE` Trigger code for your trigger.  Copy and paste it into your query tool, change `CREATE` to `ALTER`  and make the necessary changes and commit.

Comment: yup this query is showing the complete create trigger code. but how to alter the parameters with this query  .

Comment: Refer to @seanLange commit on your origional question.  Triggers do not have parameters.  The select is to get the body of the trigger, since you need to use a migration tool and not SSMS.

Comment: ok. but variable is there inside trigger i want to change the datatype of that variable ?

Comment: So in my above comment,  "make the necessary changes..."  would be where, in the processes, you would change your variable in the Trigger.